# Modules custom templates

Tags: theming

I'm currently building a module that has a popup page in it. The popup page is very simple and no real header/footer so I don't want to use the standard html.tpl.php page.tpl.php

How can I override the master templates with my own much simpler ones?

Answer (score 1):

If memory serves me well I think the easiest way is to simply print the output in your page callback function, and not return anything:

```
function MYMODULE_popup_page_callback() {
  // Your theme variables
  $vars = array('foo' => 'bar');
  $output = theme('MYMODULE_popup_page', $vars);

  print $output;

  // If there's nothing more to be had from this page request you might as well end it (gracefully).
  drupal_exit();
}
```

The other, more involved way, would be to override the default `delivery callback` for your menu item. The default is [`drupal_deliver_html_page()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_deliver_html_page/7); if you want to go down this route I'd recommend reading and understanding that function to see what you'll need to do in your own function.

Comment: I've tried the method you suggested in code but that doesn't give me access to Drupal template vars such as $head $scripts. drupal_deliver_html_page() look like what I'm looking for, thanks.

Comment: Don't forget that if you're loading the page as an AJAX popup, it will inherit the CSS/JS already on the parent page :)

Comment: No it's not an Ajax page, just a html page with some text and links on it.

Comment: Ah ok, `drupal_deliver_html_page()` is probably the way to go then